# Why does android.harware.camera throws an error on some devices?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, camera

I made a camera app using `SurfaceHolder`, tested it on my primary device, [Samsung Galaxy J5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_J5), and *everything* looked fine.

But when I tested it on my secondary device, [S5 Neo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S5#Variants), it crashed and showed error like:

> setParameters failed

Here's the code for the error:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        camera = camera.open(1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
    camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
    camera.startFaceDetection();
    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
    parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

(And by the way, it gave me the same error but with `ColorEffect.BLACKBOARD`.)

Then I tested it on many of my friend's devices like **LG Spirit** and **Nexus 5 (AVD)** and it threw an error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

Result: It won't even start the app without crashing...

Here's the code for that error:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder ) {

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview(); //releaseCamera... is on the earlier code
            camera = camera.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    refreshCamera();
    setDisplayOrientation();

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
    camera.startFaceDetection();
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
    parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```